# amp-img variable substitution data-amp-addparams

Tags: amp-html

I would like to do the following:

```
<amp-img width="50px" height="50px" src="localhost:8080/files/id=QUERY_PARAM(id) data-amp-addparams="&type=property></amp-img>
```

Basically, I need to access this url:

"localhost:8080/files/{id}&type=property".But it does not seem to work.

It works fine with amp-list when the id is at the very end and I don't need data-amp-addparams.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable substitution is currently not supported by amp-img. I'd recommend creating a feature request for the AMP runtime [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new).